# create-react-app and relative subpaths in development

Tags: reactjs, iis, create-react-app

We are having a big environment where we have several applications under the same domain eg:

```
foo.org/a
foo.org/b
```

We have set up IIS to act in the same way on localhost, so we can type:

```
localhost/a
localhost/b
```

to reach the applications. The setup is done so to avoid CORS problems.

We are now trying to create a new application with "create-react-app" (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

To add relative paths when you build for production is no problem, the problems occur when you try to run this with `react-scripts start` on localhost.
It seems it doesn't support relative paths so it always try to fetch build.js and other resources from `/`and there is not possible to set this without ejecting webpack.

So my question is, do you have any good ways of sorting this out? Ejecting webpack is not a good solution for us.

Comment: Just for interest - why is ejecting webpack not a good solution for you?

Comment: Because that will result in we have to maintain the configuration ourself, which is something the team currently want to aviod (internal politics is always fun) :)

Comment: Oh okay - that's sad ;) But I don't think that there is any other way...

Answer (score 0):

You can ejecting the config files by running: `npm run eject`

Then you'll find a config folder created in your project.

You will find your webpack config files init, where you should be able to change the "root" folder:

```
module.exports = {    
    ...
    resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, './'), // "root" folder
            ]
        }
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** Oh sorry - didn't see that ejecting is no option for you... And unfortunately I don't know any other solution.

Answer (score -1):

"homepage": "/subfolder/path", in package json file should help